# Is it good practice to use if conditional and then throw error in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch

I started with nodejs recently and every code I find uses different structure. I was wondering if there is any problem using try/catch with async/await and how error handling should be done.

```
module.exports = {
    register: async function(req, res) {
        try {

            // Check if username already exists
            const usernameDB = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
            if (usernameDB) throw new Error('Username already exists');

            // Check if email already exists
            const emailDB = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
            if (emailDB) throw new Error('Email already exists');

            // Hash the password
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(8);
            const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

            // Create a new User
            const newUser = new User({
                username: req.body.username,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: hashPassword
            });
            const savedUser = await newUser.save();
            if (!savedUser) throw new Error('Could not register you account, try again');

            res.status(201).send({
                success: true,
                message: 'Registered successfully'
            });

        }
        catch (err) {
            res.status(400).send({
                success: false,
                name: err.name,
                message: err.message
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, I am feeling myself abusing of this "save something into variable, check it and if not, throw and error".

Comment: it's fine - try/catch/finally and throw are like a family :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually is okay to do so, But if I were you I will separate these logic which you were written inside that catch block in to a controller function in a separate file. Other than that this is okay.

Comment: In addition to this answer, most of the http server impementations (express, Koa, http etc.) use the middleware pattern. You can throw the exceptions without handling it in the actual context and you can write a middleware especially for error handling.You can read more about here https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

is it good practice for using async/await. you did good job.
I think so savedUser varibale not needed.
You can save directly 
if any error throw it will be manage.

```
const newUser = new User(req.body);
 await newUser.save();
```